# Can't get Spring security to work BASIC authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to add Spring security and I can't get it to work. However I would have thought that this would cause the browser to popup a dialog asking for username and password, but nothing is shown. It just brings me the normal page without enforcing any security. Using Spring 3.1:

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

`context.xml`:

```
<security:http>
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="test" password="testpass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score -1):

you also need something like this

```
 <security:form-login login-page='/Login' authentication-failure-url="/Login?login_error=1"/>
```

And you need to create your own login page that includes at least this, and is mapped to the above url (not necessarily the same as mine obviously) :

```
<form name="f" id="f" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
  <label for="j_username">Username :&nbsp;</label>
  <input type='text' id='j_username' name='j_username'/><br/>
  <label for="j_password">Password :&nbsp;</label>
  <input type='password' id='j_password' name='j_password'><br>
```

Comment: he's trying to use http BASIC authentication not form-authentication

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your spring security context in your web.xml so the web app can load correctly your context.xml.

Here is an example on [how to do basic authentication using spring security or even with some customization](http://www.mytechtip.com/2013/04/customize-basic-authentication-in.html)